# Get Active calories burned using the Google fit Recording_API

Tags: android, google-fit

I am working on the fitness app, I need to get some information using the Recording_API to track the steps count, calories burned and distance covered. I am able to get the steps count successfully but not able to get the active calories and distance. Below I am putting the code to get the calories burned.

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.CONFIG_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, 0, this)
            .build();

Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(googleApiClient, DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        if (status.getStatusCode() == FitnessStatusCodes.SUCCESS_ALREADY_SUBSCRIBED) {
                            Log.e( "RecordingAPI", "Already subscribed to the Recording API");
                        } else {
                            Log.e("RecordingAPI", "Subscribed to get Calories using Recording API");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });



new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
            .bucketByActivitySegment(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();



Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

if (dataReadResult.getBuckets().size() > 0) {
        for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResult.getBuckets()) {
            String bucketActivity = bucket.getActivity();
            if (bucketActivity.contains(FitnessActivities.WALKING)) {
                List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
                for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                    dumpDataSet(dataSet);
                }
            }
        }
 }



for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
        if (dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) > dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                expendedCalories = expendedCalories + dp.getValue(field).asFloat();
            }
        }
 }
```

In the above code the bucket activity is coming unknown and dataPoints are coming empty due to which I am not able to get the calories. Previously I was using the HISTORY_API, using this I am able to get all the information correctly but it will only work when user has google fit account otherwise it's giving the empty results.
Can anyone please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> It will only work when user has google fit account otherwise it's giving the empty results. Can anyone please help me in this.

According to this [Quickstart for Android Google Fitness Document](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started#step_1_get_a_google_account), it is really required to have Google Account to use Fit API's.

> Step 1: Get a Google Account
>
> To use the Google Fit APIs, you need a Google Account. If you already
>   have an account, then you're all set. You may also want to create a
>   separate Google Account for testing purposes.

Comment: It will work, you only need Google Account **NOT** Google Fit account.

Comment: By the way now I am able to get the active calories burned using RECORDING_API. Thanks for your response